# How to use split in VBA for time

Tags: regex, vba, string, split

I'm very new to VBA, and for a macro I'm working on, I'm trying to split out strings of the form:

"Duration: __ Minutes __ Seconds"

I am trying to get the total time in minutes from this. However, if the time is less than a minute then it would look like

"Duration: __ Seconds"

My question is, how would I use the Split function to cover both of these cases? No need to even use split if that's easier, thanks!

So for example, if I had the string "Duration: 6 Minutes 30 Seconds", I expect the result 6.5 and if for the string "Duration: 45 Seconds" I expect 0.75.

Comment: What form? What does your input data look like? What kind of result do you expect?

Comment: The strings will either look like "Duration: 06 Minutes 30 Seconds" or "Duration: 45 Seconds", and the result that I expect is 6.5 and 0.75 respectively

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that because there was absolutely ZERO chance of me guessing that based on the post itself and I am sure that this applies for anyone else that has come across this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a user function:

```
Public Function getMinutes(ByVal input As String) As Double
    Elements = Split(input, " ") 'split the string by space
    If InStr(input, "Minutes") > 0 Then 'if the string contains the word minutes
       mins = Elements(1) 'the element at index 1 is the minutes
       secs = Elements(3) 'the element at index 3 is the seconds
    Else 'if not
       secs = Elements(1) 'just the element at index 1 is the seconds
    End If
    getMinutes = mins + secs/60 'return the minutes as they are (they may be zero) and the seconds divided by 60
End Function
```

Use it like this:

```
SampleInput1 = "Duration: 06 Minutes 30 Seconds"
myMinutes = getMinutes(SampleInput1) 'output => 6.5

SampleInput2 = "Duration: 45 Seconds"
myMinutes = getMinutes(SampleInput2) 'output => 0.75
```

You may want to test further the input against a regex expression to make sure it has the correct form before performing the operations.
[Check this brilliant answer to know how to test a string for a pattern using regex in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/3111149).
Your patterns would be:

- `Duration: \d+ Minutes \d+ Seconds`
- `Duration: \d+ Seconds`